# Как установить virtualenv и python3 внутри vagrant?

Tags: python, vagrant, virtualenv

Как установить python3 и virtualenv в Vagrant?

Answer (score 0):

В случае если VM Ubuntu - вам [сюда](http://gnperdue.github.io/vagrant/python/virtualenv/2016/01/22/setting-up-python3-in-vagrant.html).

- Python3 идёт в комплекте с системой
- Если вы именно хотите работать в virtualenv-ом под python3, то во время создания виртуальной оболочки : `virtualenv -p python3 envname`